# angular factory: how to display dynamic data?

Tags: angularjs

Hi I'am trying to display data using angularjs from a http source but can it get it to work. Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <ul ng-controller="ItemsController">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <a href="#">{{item.title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
myApp.factory('taskServices', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      getTasks: function(callback) {
        var url = 'tasks.cfc?method=list';

        $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
          callback(response.data);
        });
      }
    }
  }
]);

myApp.controller('ItemsController', ['$scope', 'taskServices',
  function($scope, taskServices) {

    $scope.items = [];
    taskServices.getTasks(function(data) {
      $scope.items = data;
    });

  }
]);
```

This code returns the following json:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"task 1"}, {"id":"2","title":"task 2"}, ]
```

but nothing is displayed. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular case, you are returning `undefined` to the `callback` function. This is because in `.success`, the first parameter is the `data`, not the `response` (unlike in `.then` where the parameter *is* `response` and there you would need `response.data` to get the data).

So, a simple fix is:

```
getTasks: function(callback){
   //... 
   $http.get(url).success(function(data){
        callback(data);
   });
}
```

But more so, you should read about [`$q` promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). This is useful, in general, when working with Angular services, built-in or third-party. You don't need to actually use `$q` directly in this case, since `$http` already returns a `$q`-promise, but it does show you how promises are used with `.then` handlers instead of a traditional callback approach.

So, I would rewrite your code a bit for `getTasks`:

```
getTasks: function(){
   //... 
   return $http.get(url) // notice the return here
      .then(function(response){
         return response.data;  // and here
      });
}
```

and in the controller:

```
taskServices.getTasks()
   .then(function(data){     
      $scope.items = data;
   });
```

In this simple example, it seems like promises substitute one approach for a just a syntactically-different promises approach, and it may be true for this example. Promises, however, have other [advantages](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/) and they align with how Angular service work (`$http`, `$timeout`, `resolve` in `ngRoute` and `ui-router`, etc...)

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick :-). I am still in the process of learning Angularjs, I will certainly read up on promises. Thanks again.